# Is it possible to shrink an MS SQL DB storage allocation (not file size) during backup but not change the db?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, backup, development-environment

This is a weird issue but I'm working with a DB and the IT team increased the allocated space by 60% which results in a db of 13GB allocated space. (This was to avoid so many resizes because DB was full) However for development I use MS SQL Express on my local machine. The DB backup file is only about 4GB cause it doesn't use all the space allocated but I can no longer restore production to express because it meets the 10GB max threshold.

My solution so far was copy production in to dev. Shrink that copy in SSMS and restore that DB into my local machine.

Is there a way to make a shrunk back up in once step? I don't want to shrink production now and cause any fragmentation.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to make a shrunk back up in once step?

No.  The empty space in the files is not copied into the backup, but the restore always creates the files with the same sizes they had when the database was backed up.

> I don't want to shrink production now and cause any fragmentation.

Very wise.

You can use [SQL Server Developer Edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads) instead of Express for larger databases.  It's also a free download, but only for Development and Test use cases.